# No data at Google Analytics Acquisition

Tags: google-analytics, data-acquisition

When I generate the GA -> Traffic acquisition report I can see no data at the Session Medium and Source.

For example : (direct)/ (none) or (not set) / (not set).
the rest of the table is OK and I can see the source URL or IP but most of the traffic came from the aforementioned.

I believe it is something related to "localhost"\hostname but I wonder where I can set any value that will help me to get better GA report?

[GA report - session seource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maOBg.png)